# jQuery's ajax encoding

Tags: php, ajax, encoding, load

I have a big problem with this ajax encoding.

I use a cyrillic file which I want to `load()` into a div, but everything I see is ����� (little squares).

I tried everything I found here and in Google, but nothing helped me. I tried to `$.ajaxSetup(ContentType: );` my ajax calls, I tried to add a `header()` in my php files... NOTHING CHANGED.

Please help! I need an IE solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The php `header()` should take care of it.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you tried to view the PHP-output directly,by calling the script in a browser? How does it look like?

Comment: @feeela: when I place header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251"); in my php file and load it directly, everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @awm: Which code do you want to place, ajax call or the php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED! Everything works fine now, because I included some system files (e.g config.php, functions.php). I had this include problem with ajax before and I still got no the answer, but that's fine. Thank you, guys!